# Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory when I run react native IOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, react-navigation

I am building a simple react-navigation app. However, whenever I run the ios simulator, I am greeted with a white screen and an error in terminal:

```
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Object.readSync (fs.js:592:3)
    at tryReadSync (fs.js:366:20)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:403:19)
    at UnableToResolveError.buildCodeFrameMessage (/Users/vaibhavherugu/Books2Go/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:347:17)
    at new UnableToResolveError (/Users/vaibhavherugu/Books2Go/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:333:35)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/vaibhavherugu/Books2Go/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:211:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/vaibhavherugu/Books2Go/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:413:43)
    at /Users/vaibhavherugu/Books2Go/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:317:42
    at /Users/vaibhavherugu/Books2Go/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1471:14
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

This is my app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import Login from './components/Login.js';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Thanks.